for EOA to EOA simple value transfer transactions, how is the EVM state updated if no EVM operations are performed?
I understand that the EVM is mostly used to run smart contracts computations, and not involved for EOA to EOA simple value transfer transactions. However, then how is the world state Trie updated no EVM operations are performed for those transactions? Or does the state update take place somewhere else outside of the EVM, and then propagated to the nodes?

While EVM does make changes to the World state trie, the trie lives outside of EVM. Only volatile data live inside EVM - which gets thrown away and reset on every transaction.
Once the transaction is ran valid in a node, the same transaction is propagated to its peers and eventually added to a new block.
